# jpg image file can't be open after OSS upload

Tags: file-upload, blob, image-upload, react-native-image-picker, react-native-blob-util

The React Native 0.70 app uses `react-native-blob-util` to read jpg image file from image picker before uploading it to OSS. Here is the code:

```
import ReactNativeBlobUtil from "react-native-blob-util"; //v0.19
const fileData = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.readFile(filePath, 'base64'); //filePath is the file path from image picker
const fileData1 = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${fileData}`
```

The `fileData1` was uploaded with `fetch`:

```
const response = await fetch(preSignedUrl, {. //preSignedUrl is acquired from backend node server
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' },
    body: fileData1,
  })
```

The image uploaded can't be open. The md5(fileData1) before `fetch PUT` is the same as the md5 returned from OSS. It may be related to the jpg file format on OSS but not sure where is the issue.

UPDATE:
return of `await fetch(filePath)` (fetch fileData1 throws error):

```
LOG  responsefetch in uploadTOOSS:  {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "44313295-9de3-4dfe-b9be-bbdef6110f4b", "lastModified": 0, "name": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_9373b67e-6f10-4932-b743-f2155da4fca8.jpg", "offset": 0, "size": 47367, "type": "image/jpeg"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "44313295-9de3-4dfe-b9be-bbdef6110f4b", "lastModified": 0, "name": "rn_image_picker_lib_temp_9373b67e-6f10-4932-b743-f2155da4fca8.jpg", "offset": 0, "size": 47367, "type": "image/jpeg"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"content-type": "image/jpeg"}}, "ok": false, "status": 0, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": ""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are uploading the base64-encoded image data directly to the [OSS (Object Storage Service)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_storage#Architecture) using a pre-signed URL.

When you encode the file content in base64 and prepend the data URL schema (`data:image/jpeg;base64`), it is suitable for embedding images directly into web pages or CSS files (see "[How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8499633/6309)" for instance).
However, for uploading to OSS, you should convert the base64 back to binary data because the storage expects the raw binary format of the image, not its base64-encoded representation.

So you need to convert the base64-encoded string back to binary before uploading. That can be done using the [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) or [`Buffer` API](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html), but since you are working in a [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) environment, you will have to rely on what is available there. Unfortunately, React Native does not have the same global `Blob` constructor as web browsers, but [`react-native-blob-util`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blob-util) provides a workaround.

```js
import ReactNativeBlobUtil from "react-native-blob-util";

// Step 1: Convert base64 to binary
const blob = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.base64ToBlob(fileData);

// Step 2: Upload the blob
const response = await fetch(preSignedUrl, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' },
  body: blob, // Use the blob directly
});
```

You need to make sure [`base64ToBlob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64toblob) correctly converts the base64 string to a binary format that `fetch` can handle. If `react-native-blob-util` does not directly support `base64ToBlob`, you might have to use `fetch` to create a blob from the base64 string, like:

```js
// Convert base64 to blob using fetch
const response = await fetch(fileData1);
const blob = await response.blob();

// Then upload this blob as before
```

---

> Unfortunately `ReactNativeBlobUtil.base64ToBlob` does not exist in the module.
> `fetch(fileData1)` throws error of network request failed.
> Converting base64 to blob shall be a way to go. Just a matter of how to do it in React Native.

Since `ReactNativeBlobUtil.base64ToBlob` does not exist, and that the `fetch(fileData1)` approach results in a network error, you might consider instead to manually converting the base64 string to binary data, and then upload this binary data using `fetch`.

Try and create a function to convert the base64 string to a binary format that `fetch` can handle as binary data, using the [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array):

```js
// Helper function to convert base64 to Uint8Array
function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
  const binaryString = atob(base64); // Decode base64
  const len = binaryString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes;
}

// Assuming `fileData` is your base64-encoded image data without the data URL prefix
const binaryData = base64ToUint8Array(fileData);

// Upload binary data
const response = await fetch(preSignedUrl, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' },
  body: binaryData, // Use the binary data directly
});
```

That would manually convert the base64-encoded string to a binary format (`Uint8Array`) that is then uploaded.
It is a bit lower level and circumvents the need for a `Blob`, which should be a good fit considering the capabilities and limitations of React Native's environment.

The [`atob` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob) used in the conversion process is a built-in JavaScript function that decodes a base64-encoded string. However, it might not be available in all React Native environments. If `atob` is not available in your React Native environment, you might need to use a polyfill or an alternative method to decode the base64 string. Libraries such as [`react-native-blob-util`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blob-util?activeTab=readme) might offer similar functionality, or you can use a third-party library to decode base64 strings.

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938363/user938363) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78010257/jpg-image-file-cant-be-open-after-oss-upload/78019333?noredirect=1#comment137550703_78019333) making it work:

> Here is the one worked to overcome `atob`.
>
> - install `base-64` and `import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'`.
> - Do `const binaryString = decode(base64);` in the function above.
>
> The rest works like charm..

Comment: Hi `VonC`,  thanks for the solution posted. unfortunately ReactNativeBlobUtil.base64ToBlob does not exist in the module.  `fetch(fileData1)` throws error of network request failed. Converting base64 to blob shall be a way to go. Just a matter of how to do it in react native.

Comment: there is a new issue posted under react native blob util. https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/issues/336 about converting base64 to blob.  react-native-blob-util seems not having a ready solution. atob is not available in react native. I tried xmlhttprequest with formdata and it introduces a new error (isTrusted:false). OSS seems very unfriendly with form data anyway.

Comment: Here is the one worked to overcome atob. install base-64 and import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'.  do `const binaryString = decode(base64);` in the function above. The rest works like charm. Many thanks.

Comment: @user938363 Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: thank you. you can remove section about ReactNativeBlobUtil.wrap as you like. As far as I understand, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user938363 OK. I have removed that section.